# Extend sfGuardUser : adding "phone number" field

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

DOCTRINE 1.2 // SYMFONY 1.4

Hi!
in my website, am using the `sfGuardPlugin`'s tables with the other tables in order to set an alarm system, the app gets to the users mails in order to get the mails and send the email, 
now i need also a phone number for sending sms !
all i need is an extra field ("`phone`") in the `sfGuardUser` 'table,
i have been wondering if i could do it with "`inheritence`" but am stuck in the type (simple, concrete? ...)
any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you are having trouble simply creating the field in your database/model. If this is the case:

For example - if you are defining your tables in the schema.yml file, you could basically do something like this:

```
sfGuardUser:
  columns:
    somecolumn:
      type: string
```

Just specify the sfGuardUser as it was a new, non-existing class and add your fields. The other (and in some cases better) way would be creating a new table for profile fields and using the sfGuardUser id as foreign key.

If the problem is with something else, let me know.

Comment: i ve solved the problem by using inheritance : type simple and addind my field !
thanks anyway !

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use sf_guard_user_profile table for add custom field? It's the recommended method.

```
sf_guard_user_profile:
  _attributes: { phpName: sfGuardUserProfile }
  id:          ~
  user_id:     { type: integer, foreignTable: sf_guard_user, foreignReference: id, required: true, onDelete: cascade }
  phone:       varchar(20)
```

Then you can use:

```
$this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getProfile()->getPhone()
```

or

```
$this->getUser()->getProfile()->getPhone()
```

Anyway, if you want/need to "extend" sfGuardUser you have to modify the plugin schema.yml, add your field and rebuild all classes. I advise you against. ;-)

Comment: Yup, that's the normal way. From what I can see, [this article on adding extra fields using the sfGuardUserProfile from the Symfony Blog](http://symfony.com/blog/call-the-expert-customizing-sfdoctrineguardplugin) is fairly up-to-date and might fill in some extra details.

Answer (score 0):

i ve solved the problem by using inheritance : type simple and addind my field ! thanks anyway !

```
Myuser:
  inheritance:
    extends: sfGuardUser
    type: simple
  columns:
    gsm:
      type: string(30)
```

This way the field "gsm" will appear in sfGuardUser table and be automatically managed by the plugin (i won't have to use MyUser)

I can get now the phone number by using : getGsm() ....from sfGuardUser object  !
Thank you everybody !